# Cannot get particular attribute values using relation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three models category,attribute and attribute values, from below code i'm getting all the attributes and its values of a particular category but i want value of a particular attribute.

For eg. if I have an attribute Color i only want that particular attribute and its values, so i want to write a new controller method to get only those attribute, attribute values whose id i pass as a parameter.

Will same model relation be sufficient for this or i have to create new model.
Models:

> Categories

```
id | category_name
```

> Attributes

```
id | category_id | attr_name
```

> Attribute Values

```
id | attribute_id | value
```

> Category Model:

```
 public function categoryAttributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class, 'category_id');
    }
```

> Attribute Model:

```
 public function attrValues()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(AttributeValues::class,'attribute_id');
   }
```

> View:

```
@foreach($category->categoryAttributes as $attr)
  {{ $attr->attr_name }}
  @foreach($attr->attrValues as $attr_value)
   $attr_value->value
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

> Controller:

```
Category::where('id',$categoryId)->with(['categoryAttributes.attrValues'])->first();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to add **{{ }}**

`{{ $attr_value->value }}`

---

## Edit

Since what you want is just an attribute with it's values, then create a new method.

```
public function fetchAttribute(Request $request)
{
    $attribute = Attribute::with('attrValues')->find($request->get('attr_id'));

    return response()->json($attribute);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to get specific attribute and its value how will i write that in my controller and view, but from my above code i'm getting all the attribute and attribute values.

Comment: Do you have attribute id passed in the request?

Comment: :yes attribute id will be passed through ajax function to the controller, I have to show that particular attribute and it attribute values in the modal

Comment: Updated my answer. Please have a look.